# IArtifactRepositoryManager is null with Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.2

Tags: eclipse-rcp, p2

The following function worked perfectly in **Eclipse Neon 4.6.x** target runtime for a very long time:

```
public static boolean addRepository(IProvisioningAgent agent, String repo) {
    Utils.log(String.format("adding repository at %s", repo));
    IMetadataRepositoryManager metadataManager = (IMetadataRepositoryManager) agent.getService(IMetadataRepositoryManager.SERVICE_NAME);
    IArtifactRepositoryManager artifactManager = (IArtifactRepositoryManager) agent.getService(IArtifactRepositoryManager.SERVICE_NAME);
    if (metadataManager == null || artifactManager == null) {
        Utils.log("P2Utils.addRepository - missing metadata or artifact manager");
        return false;
    }

    try {
        URI uri = new URI(repo);
        metadataManager.addRepository(uri);
        artifactManager.addRepository(uri);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Utils.log(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

It stopped working with **Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.2** target, the **artifactManager** returned is always null. Does anyone involved knows what was changed and how to fix this? It breaks our updates.., I am at a loss where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the response from [eclipse forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1092937&goto=1786119&#msg_1786119), there were some plugins missing:
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf